# Proof check for connectivity of connected components

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Let $X$ be a topological space. Declare $x\sim y$ in $X$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are contained in some connected subspace of $X$. Then it's easily seen to be an equivalence relation. I am trying to show that any equivalence class $C$ is connected. I came up with the following argument. I'd be grateful if anyone can validate it.

**Proof:** Let $C$ be a disjoint union of the sets $U\cap C$ and $V\cap C$ ($U$, $V$ open in $X$). We need to show that one of these is empty. If possible, choose $x\in U\cap C$ and $y\in V\cap C$. Now, take a connected subspace $Y$ that contains both $x$ and $y$, and observe that $Y\subseteq C$ so that $Y = Y\cap C$, getting that $Y$ is a disjoint union of nonempty opens $U\cap Y$ and $V\cap Y$, contradicting the connectivity of $Y$.

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense.  Once you pass to the (quotient) space $X/\sim$, the equivalence classes are *points* not sets in this space. In your original statement if you define $x\sim y$ if they are in the same connected component (these are the maximal connected subspaces) then $X/\sim$ will be discrete and totally disconnected (each point is its own connected component).

Comment: @AlgTop1854 By $X/\sim$, I meant the set of equivalence classes, not the quotient topology. Maybe I should delete it to avert the confusion.

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: @Atom or revise a bit to clarify; which you seem to have done.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 One small point of correction (which is not super important since OP has revised anyway).  Each point will be its own component, so yes, $X/\sim$ will be totally disconnected, but in general it need not be discrete (consider $X=\mathbb Q$ or any other totally disconnected non-discrete space, then $\sim$ is trivial and the quotient space is homeomorphic to the original).

Comment: Thanks - you are right - it's easy to think discrete when imagining points are connected components but that's not the case.